# Including external plugins

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, ngx-leaflet

Is it possible to include **[extern plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html)** to my **[ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet)** app?

Because I would have to implement **[Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision)** and **[Leaflet.Arc](https://github.com/mad-gooze/Leaflet.Arc)**, but I don't know how to do it. Please let me know if you have an idea :)

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Check this out as a starting point: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-plugins

Comment: @reblace First of all, thanks all the work, it's really awesome! I tried to reproduce your answer here https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/issues/101 with the mentioned (Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision) package. I installed the package itself and its dependency **rbush**, then i included rbush in the **cli dependencies**, tried to adapt it to TypeScript with: _import * as L from 'leaflet';
declare module 'leaflet' {
   var leafletLayergroupCollision: any;
}_        and  imported Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collusion in the app.component, but it doesn't work :/ Sorry if I haven't understood something